# Rasterize Vector MultiLine

Tags: qgis, saga, rasterization

I try to rasterize a multiline data set (streets) from a PostGIS database using *QGIS 2.18* and *SAGA GIS rasterize tool*.

I managed to differentiate between *street* and *not street* but I'd need to differentiate the raster value for different road classes (1-10). I tried to set the *attribute field* as the respective field and chose *attribute* in the *output value field*. [image: SAGA GIS rasterize]
Unfortunately, output seems to be more as an index from 1 to 2500 than values from 1 to 10.

I also tried GDAL rasterize and GRASS v.to.rast.value. Output of the GRASS GIS is just binary (street/no street)

In the end I'd need a "categorized" raster for diffeerent kinds of road types and nodata values in the other area. It will be one layer of a suitability analysis which I plan to do with raster calculator.

Question:

How can rasterize a multiline vector file and keep the value of a particular attribute?

**update 1:** SAGA GIS uses the value of *ID field* instead of "_objectval_id_.
**update 2:** GDAL tool would work, but I'm not able to set the raster resolution properly.
**update 3:** obviously *SAGA GIS rasterize* only works when the attribute is unambiguous assigned. So I'd have to use indices for every road class or create for every class a single raster layer. correct?

Comment: **solution**: I created a new field with field calculator as 
`
    CASE 
        WHEN  "id" <10 THEN "Objectval_ID"  || '.' ||  0 || 0  || "id"   
            WHEN 9< "id" AND "id"<100 THEN "Objectval_ID"  || '.' ||  0 || "id"  
               WHEN 99< "id" THEN "Objectval_ID"  || '.'  || "id" 
    END 
`
Rasterizing this with SAGA Rasterize tool into integer gives only the road value!

Comment: You should post your _comment_ as an **answer** :)

Comment: @Joseph, thx; I wasn't sure if this is a solution or just an odd workaround...

Comment: It could be both :). But as long as it helped you solve your problem, it should be posted as an answer as it could help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new field with field calculator as

```
CASE WHEN "id" <10 THEN "Objectval_ID" || '.' || 0 || 0 || "id"
        WHEN 9< "id" AND "id"<100 THEN "Objectval_ID" || '.' || 0 || "id"   
            WHEN 99< "id" THEN "Objectval_ID" || '.' || "id" 
END
```

Rasterizing this with SAGA Rasterize tool into integer gives only the road value!